# Why webservice thread not terminating?

Tags: java, web-services

I have a webservice, which creates a new thread to serve each of the new requests, but the thread is not getting terminated after serving the particular request. Hence the system getting slow and eventually crashed. So could you please let me know is the expected behavior or is there any configuration I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: Without any more information it's hard to help. Care to show a mcve for your case? And did you debug/check what the threads that should have died are doing (you could use jconsole with the top-threads plugin for that)?

Comment: Hi, I am using jvisualvm to monitor the behavior, and I could see the spring's ThreadPoolTaskExecutor thread getting created for each of the requests. and the thread remains forever even after it serves the request.

Comment: I don't know spring's `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` but it being created upon every request hints at misconfiguration/misuse. I'd say there should be a defined number of executors which is managed by the application/framework and based on the number of available cores etc., so the application should just create new tasks and hand them over to the task pool for execution. Can you provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: thank you for the inputs. sorry I cant get the mcve as it is confidential. I would try to recreate in an example and post it here if possible.